# Get non-numeric characters then number on each line of a block of texf

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, numeric, text-parsing

I have some strings which can be in the following format:

```
sometext moretext 01 text
text sometext moretext 002
text text 1 (somemoretext)
etc
```

I want to split these strings into following:

- text before the number and
- the number

For example:

```
text text 1 (somemoretext)
```

When split will output:

text = `text text`
number = `1`

Anything after the number can be discarded.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
preg_match('/[^\d]+/', $string, $textMatch);
preg_match('/\d+/', $string, $numMatch);

$text = $textMatch[0];
$num = $numMatch[0];
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `preg_match_all` with capture groups to do it all in one shot:

```
preg_match_all('/^([^\d]+)(\d+)/', $string, $match);

$text = $match[1][0];
$num = $match[2][0];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) + if you wish to match every line use [m modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.internal-options.php):

```
$string = 'sometext moretext 01 text
text sometext moretext 002
text text 1 (somemoretext)
etc';
preg_match_all('~^(.*?)(\d+)~m', $string, $matches);
```

All your results are in `$matches` array, which looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => sometext moretext 01
            [1] => text sometext moretext 002
            [2] => text text 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => sometext moretext 
            [1] => text sometext moretext 
            [2] => text text 
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01
            [1] => 002
            [2] => 1
        )
)
```

Output example:

```
foreach ($matches[1] as $k => $text) {
    $int = $matches[2][$k];
    echo "$text => $int\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers do not demonstrate the use of `\D` to match non-digit characters.  `\D` is the opposite of `\d`.

`*` as a quantifier means zero or more and `+` means one or more.  Quantifiers immediately followed by `?` are made "lazy" -- effectively they try to make the shortest qualifying match, but this has a negative impact on performance and should be avoided when possible.

The `^` means the start of a line when the pattern has a `m` flag.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/66qDK))

```
$text = 'sometext moretext 01 text
text sometext moretext 002
text text 1 (somemoretext)
etc';

preg_match_all('/^(\D*)(\d+)/m', $text, $matches);

var_export([
    'non-digit' => $matches[1],
    'digit' => $matches[2]
]);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'non-digit' => 
  array (
    0 => 'sometext moretext ',
    1 => 'text sometext moretext ',
    2 => 'text text ',
  ),
  'digit' => 
  array (
    0 => '01',
    1 => '002',
    2 => '1',
  ),
)
```

If you want to discard potential spaces at the end of the non-numeric string, add `?` to make the first group lazy and match zero or more whitespace characters without capturing. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Iddhc))

```
preg_match_all('/^(\D*?)\s*(\d+)/m', $text, $matches);
```