# how to separate the string and number in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I retrieve some string like (A00001) from mysql. I want to separate these like A and 00001.

After separation that values increased one (A00002), these process will do, when click submit button.

Comment: Are your data always in this format : 6 characters (1 Letter + 5 digits) ?

Comment: For the record, you need not tamper with it, PHP can handle incrementing strings like that. `$a = "A00001"; var_dump(++$a)` will result in "A00002".

Comment: please suggest for this question....get value from table row and set into text box. see my jsfiddle file [ http://jsfiddle.net/yXFZs/ ]

Answer (score 2):

Something like this may do the work

```
$string = "A00001";

preg_match_all('/[^\d]+/', $string, $textArray);
preg_match('/\d+/', $string, $numbersArray);

$text = $textArray[0];
$number = $numbersArray[0];
```

originaly from [Split String into Text and Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348018/split-string-into-text-and-number)

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = "A00001";
var letters = text.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, ""); 
var digits = text.replace(/\D/g, "");
alert(letters);
alert(digits);
```

[check this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/UHKJn/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$value = 'A00001';
$letter = substr($value, 0, 1);
$number = (int) substr($value, 1)

$number++;

$value = $letter.str_pad($number, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

[str_pad()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) is used to add extra 0 in beginning of number if it as less than 5 characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the format is alqays the same (1 letter and 5 numbers), you can use that.

```
$string = 'A00001';
$letter = substr($string, 0, 1);
$number = substr($string, 1);
```

If there are any letters and any numbers, use the regex.

It´s for PHP, for JS it´ll be similar.

Comment: please suggest for this question....get value from table row and set into text box. see my jsfiddle file [ http://jsfiddle.net/yXFZs/ ]

Answer (score 0):

In what language? If you want to extract in PHP you can use a regular expression. This example breaks out the letter and the digits and gives you an associative array:

```
preg_match('/^(?<letter>\w)(?<digits>\d+)$/', "A00001", $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => A00001
    [letter] => A
    [1] => A
    [digits] => 00001
    [2] => 00001
)
```

In JavaScript you can adapt the same technique:

```
var str = "A00001";
var matches = str.match(/(\w)(\d+)/);
console.log(matches);  // ["A00001", "A", "00001"]
```

Comment: please suggest for this question....get value from table row and set into text box. see my jsfiddle file [ http://jsfiddle.net/yXFZs/ ]