# How to split a string from integers in php?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this:

```
$str="hello world 2 in 365 php";
```

I want this:

```
['hello world' , 'in' , 'php']
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve]. Follow those guidelines. And show what you've tried so far and where you got stuck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split String into Text and Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348018/split-string-into-text-and-number)

Comment: Alternatively you can use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was bored:

```
$result = preg_split('/ ?\d+ ?/', $str);
```

Split on an optional space `?` followed by 1 or more digits `\d+` followed by an optional space `?`.  Just remove the `?`s if you want the spaces to be required.

Answer (score 0):

That would do the work for you (I've split into multiple variables just to make sure you understand the way I've done that)

```
$str = "hello world 2 in 365 php";
$withoutNum = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $str);
$removedDoubleWhiteSpaces = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $withoutNum);

$splitedArr = explode(' ', $removedDoubleWhiteSpaces);

var_dump($splitedArr);
```

**Edit:**

After I've read again, the solution which offered above of my solution is the ideal one. Sorry.

Comment: This would also split "hello" and "world" into two entries in the array.

Comment: Right, just saw what he meant to achieve. The above solution is the ideal one then.