# get the value of combined string and integer separately

Tags: php

I got this result from mysql query using php:

```
chris123
```

I want to separate `chris` from `123` because I am going to use the value of int for operation.

```
$char=string('chris123');
$int=int('chris123');
```

How am I able to do it in PHP? Not PDO. Not so familiar with it. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split String into Text and Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348018/split-string-into-text-and-number)

Comment: Definitely a duplicate as @BojanSrbinoski stated. Follow that link and it'll do exactly as you are seeking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the non-number parts are always going to be lowercase characters, you can do this:

```
$str = 'chris123';
$num = trim($str, 'a..z');
```

If you also want it to be an actual integer, you can cast it:

```
$str = 'chris123';
$num = (int) trim($str, 'a..z');
```

Comment: thanks i got the integer already. how about the string chris? thanks

Comment: Just trim the digits instead.